# Accessing static resources in Spring Boot v2.1.7.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot, static

I am very new to Spring-Boot and Bootstrap.
I'm trying to load static resources, and this is what my project structure looks like.
[image]

I saw that Spring-boot-starter lets "/" to access "/static", so if I add  tag like on the screenshot I uploaded,

```html
<script src="/js/app/index.js"></script>
```

then it should load file from /src/main/resources/static/js/app/index.js.
I tried every solution I saw on stackoverflow and google, but I couldn't find the answer.
Please help me.

Also, my `Application.java` file is as described below.

```java
@EnableJpaAuditing
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

If I Build my application and load it, web browser console messages says
`net::ERR_ABORTED 404` on every static resources that I try to load.

Answer (score 0):

Spring boot will automatically serve any resources under the directories :

```
/META-INF/resources/  
/resources/  
/static/  
/public
```

but you have a sub folder `/app` in your project for these static asssets. So if you keep everything like :

```
/static/css/
/static/js/
```

and so on it should work. Or else you could provide your own folder structure for the static assets by customizing the bean like :

```
@Configuration
public class StaticConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/custom/");
    }
}
```